# Expanding a dataframe based on a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame looks like below (but much longer):

```
Column_A  Column_B  Column_C
Bob       Henry     3
Bill      Alice     2
...
```

I want to expand this data frame based on column c:

```
Column_A  Column_B  Column_C
Bob       Henry     1
Bob       Henry     1
Bob       Henry     1
Bill      Alice     1
Bill      Alice     1
...
```

Basically, the numbers in the column c of the original data frame determines the number of duplicated rows (For example, in the original data frame, the first row has value of 3 in column C and thus in the new data frame, there are will be three rows with "Bob" in column A and "Henry" in column B).

Comment: `tidyr::uncount(df, Column_C) %>% mutate(Column_C = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = your_data[rep(1:nrow(your_data), times = your_data$Column_C), ]
result$Column_C = 1
```